# Angular + TypeScript + AMD = duplication?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I've been developing in Angular for a few months and am now investigating whether it's worth moving to TypeScript for my development. One of the issues I'm having is the duplication when using external modules and injecting services. For example I have this (simplified) code:

```
///<reference path="../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

// imports for strong typing
import audioModel = require('app/plugins/audio/audio.model');

export class AudioController {

    public model: audioModel;

    static $inject = ['$scope', '$q', 'AudioModel'];
    constructor(protected $scope, protected $q, protected AudioModel:audioModel) {
        this.model = new AudioModel();
    }

}
```

The *AudioModel* is an Angular factory defined in the external module 'audio.model.ts', so it seems to me that I'm injecting it twice - once using Angular, and again using the TypeScript import to get strong typing.

Is there a better way to both use Angular dependency injection and strong typing in an AMD project?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to both use Angular dependency injection and strong typing in an AMD project

This was an issue with angular 1.x dependency injection. The Angular module system was *independent* of the traditional Browser module systems in existance (e.g. AMD).

So you do need to import it twice. Once the Type, next the DI.